# Springdoc-ui + GraalVM native @Configuration classes issue

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, springdoc, graalvm-native-image, springdoc-openapi-ui

Pursuing my quest of learning details of GraalVM + SpringBoot, I'm working on a sample application with just a small set of operations and features.
One of those is the possibility of exposing the SpringDoc endpoints (currently using version 1.4.5).
Even though the application is been compiled properly and the native image executable fires up, it raises an exception as soon as it starts configuring stuff:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: @Configuration classes need to be marked as proxyBeanMethods=false. Found: [org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties, org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigParameters, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiConfigProperties, org.springdoc.core.SwaggerUiOAuthProperties, org.springdoc.webmvc.core.SpringDocWebMvcConfiguration, org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerConfig]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:71) ~[poc-graalvm-native.exe:na]
```

I already have the following dependencies:

```
    implementation("org.springframework.experimental:spring-graalvm-native:0.7.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework:spring-context-indexer:5.2.4.RELEASE")
```

And also have `@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)` on my main class.

Is there any workaround for these cases of @Configuration classes without proxyBeanMethods=false property?

**UPDATE**:
It seems like configurations were updated on Springdoc 1.4.6-Snapshot. However, something else started to complain:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'modelConverterRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/SpringDocConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springdoc.core.converters.ModelConverterRegistrar]: Factory method 'modelConverterRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

No clue where to go now...

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since `v1.5.9`springdoc-openapi [fully supports](https://springdoc.org/#graalvm-and-spring-native-for-native-images) GraalVM with spring-native.

No additional configuration required.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.
I am now using version 1.4.6, and the corrections you pointed out previously are already present on my native image configurations.
But I still have the last error mentioned in my question.